# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::products()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, search-engine

i am trying to Implement smart Search engine in my Laravel 5 With help of This Tutorial
https://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/laravel-shop-tutorial-3-implementing-smart-search/
i changes some code because this tutorial for laravel 4
now i am stuck here When i type any keywords like cup i got error on Network tab in my deleveloper tool

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::products()
```

Here is my Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;
use Response;

class ApiSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function appendValue($data, $type, $element)
    {
        // operate on the item passed by reference, adding the element and type
        foreach ($data as $key => & $item) {
            $item[$element] = $type;
        }
        return $data;       
    }

    public function appendURL($data, $prefix)
    {
        // operate on the item passed by reference, adding the url based on slug
        foreach ($data as $key => & $item) {
            $item['url'] = url($prefix.'/'.$item['slug']);
        }
        return $data;       
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $query = e(Input::get('q',''));

        if(!$query && $query == '') return Response::json(array(), 400);

        $products = Product::where('published', true)
            ->where('name','like','%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('name','asc')
            ->take(5)
            ->get(array('slug','name','icon'))->toArray();

        $categories = Category::where('name','like','%'.$query.'%')
            ->has('products')
            ->take(5)
            ->get(array('slug', 'name'))
            ->toArray();

        // Data normalization
        $categories = $this->appendValue($categories, url('img/icons/category-icon.png'),'icon');

        $products   = $this->appendURL($products, 'products');
        $categories  = $this->appendURL($categories, 'categories');

        // Add type of data to each item of each set of results
        $products = $this->appendValue($products, 'product', 'class');
        $categories = $this->appendValue($categories, 'category', 'class');

        // Merge all data into one array
        $data = array_merge($products, $categories);

        return Response::json(array(
            'data'=>$data
        ));
    }
}
```

my Product and Category model is blank because nothing on tutorial

Comment: Post your category model.

Comment: you have to set the relation in your models and database to use that

Comment: Hey my both model is blank what should I type there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well based on your relationship between **Product** and **Category** Models you have to define product() function inside **Category** Model which represents your relationship. check [This Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)

For example - Assuming **One-to-Many** relationship (one category - Many Products) it will be like this -

**Category Model** -

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
                     // ^ this will change based on relationship
    }
}
```

**Product Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
                       // ^ this will change based on relationship
    }
}
```